# Replace text/image of Tkinter logo

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a question regarding the Tkinter logo which appears in the top left corner of the Tk window. I would like to  know how to change the name, and eventually replace the whole thing with an alternate logo. Is this possible?
The tried to write to the following property that i saw on another thread but no luck:

```
master=Tk()
master.title("name")
#Note I have also tried master.title= "name"
```

Does anybody have the secret?

Daniel W.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered reading about this years ago and yes the thread was still there, but looks like it takes an icon bitmap only  http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/63769/tk-logo-on-gui-window  If you find another way please post it.

Comment: This is the thread, which i had working at some point                    http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/                                                                                                   Somehow using this thread (check out the if statement after the class construct) I managed to replace the Tk name but not the logo, but i cant get it to work now. Now im getting an str error. Not sure what I am doing differently except using it outside the class construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import Tk
frame = Tk()
frame.geometry('300x300') #Frame size (width,height)
frame.title('Frame Title') # Frame title
frame.iconbitmap('logo.ico') # Frame logo
frame.mainloop()
```

its work for me!.